# Majorisation inequality/upper bound

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions

I saw the following relation and now I'm trying to prove it

$$\sum_{i=1}^l a^{\downarrow}_i  \geq \sum_i \{a_i | a_i \geq 1/l \} \, ,$$

but I'm stuck. Here $a^{\downarrow}_i$ is an element, in non-increasing order, of a probability vector $\textbf{a}$. For example, considering the probability vector $\textbf{p} = (1/2, 3/8, 1/8)$ and choosing $l = 2$, one has

$$ \sum_{i=1}^2 p^{\downarrow}_i = \frac{7}{8} \, ,$$

while the right-hand side yields

$$ \sum_i \{p_i | p_i \geq 1/2 \} = \frac{1}{2} \, ,$$

then easily the inequality is verified. Could you please give me a hint or recommend something to read that will help me to prove it?

Thank you very much,

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily proved by the follows:

In the new array $a^{\downarrow}$ which is in non-increasing order, it cannot be that the first $l$ elements are all larger than $1/l$, otherwise the sum of them must exceed $1$. Therefore, the right hand side of the inequality must be
\begin{align}
&\sum_i \{ a_i | a_i \geq 1/l \} \\
=& \sum_i \{ a_i^{\downarrow} | a_i^{\downarrow} \geq 1/l \} \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^{\downarrow},
\end{align}
where the $m$ is smaller than or equal to $l$ by the above analysis. Therefore, it must be that
\begin{align}
&\sum_i \{ a_i | a_i \geq 1/l \} \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^{\downarrow} \\
\leq & \sum_{i=1}^l a_i^{\downarrow}.
\end{align}

Comment: This problem actually has nothing to do with probability, except that it used the property that the elements of a probability vector sum to one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mianlai. But how can I gurantee that $\sum_i \{ a_i | a_i \geq 1/l \} 
= \sum_i \{ a_i^{\downarrow} | a_i^{\downarrow} \geq 1/l \}$? Although your summing there is a condition that you need to fullfill. Right?

Comment: @AlexssandredeOliveiraJ It is because $\{ a_i^{\downarrow} \}$ is simply a permutation of $\{ a_i \}$ but in a non-increasing order, therefore there must have $\sum_i \{ a_i | a_i \geq 1/l \} = \sum_i \{ a_i^{\downarrow} | a_i^{\downarrow} \geq 1/l \} = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^{\downarrow}$ for some m.